# C++ conversion: have pointer to object member, calculate pointer to object

Tags: c++, pointers, static-cast, member-pointers, pointer-conversion

C++ has `static_cast` to convert `base_class_pointer` to `derived_class_pointer`.

It is very similar operation to convert `object_data_member_pointer` to `object_pointer`.

I wrote the function `ConvertDataMemberPtrToObjectPtr` using unsafe C type conversion.

- How can this be done in a safe way? Link to the member must be specified as a template parameter `member_ptr`.
- Whether there can be any problems if you use such an implementation?

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

template< class T, class Member_type, Member_type T::*member_ptr >
inline T *ConvertDataMemberPtrToObjectPtr(Member_type& member) {    
    //Got reference to member 'member' of object 'T', return pointer to object 'T'
    // obj_ptr = member_ptr - offset_of_member_field
    return (T*) ( ((char*)(&member)) - ( (char*) (  &( ((T*)(0))->*member_ptr ) )  ) );
}

struct Test {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    Test obj;

    printf("\n0x%08lX", ConvertDataMemberPtrToObjectPtr<Test,int,&Test::a>(obj.a));
    printf("\n0x%08lX", ConvertDataMemberPtrToObjectPtr<Test,int,&Test::b>(obj.b));

    // This is must be avoided when using ConvertDataMemberPtrToObjectPtr!!!
    printf("\n0x%08lX - error!", ConvertDataMemberPtrToObjectPtr<Test,int,&Test::a>(obj.b));

    return 0;
}
```

Using parents instead members and `static_cast`:

```
template <class T, int id=0>
class Link {
public:
    int value;
    T *GetObjectPtr() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
};
enum MyLinkId { Main=0, Red=1 };
class MyItem : public Link<MyItem,Main>, public Link<MyItem,Red> {};

MyItem x;
Link<MyItem,Main> *p2 = &x;
Link<MyItem,Red> *p3 = &x;

printf("\n0x%08lX", p2->GetObjectPtr());
printf("\n0x%08lX", p3->GetObjectPtr());
```

Comment: Why not use `obj` directly since you have it? If you can't in your real code, then ugly casts are your only resort.

Comment: I consider the case described in the template. I think this conversion can sometimes be useful. In my problem, I decided to use multiple inheritance and `static_cast`.

Comment: Accessing the value through MyItem will be ambiguous!

Comment: Yes. `int value` must be private for Link.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible: The information to distinguish the members is missing.
You would need a unique reference member which you could pass to your conversion function.

```
struct UniqueReferenceMember {};
struct Test {
    UniqueReferenceMember unique_reference_member;
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Having that is pointless, though. There is the object pointer, which you can pass directly (maybe converted to void*);

Comment: I want to avoid "unsafe C type conversion" in `return (T*)...`. It seems to me that your answer about `printf("\n0x%08lX - error!"...` problem, but it is not my point.

Comment: No - I am addressing your attempt to distinguish the members.